# How to find Not Used Pub IP Objects in Azure Resource Manager using powershell

Tags: azure

How can i find UNUSED or Unassociated PubIP IP Object in a Azure resource group using powershell.

I want to delete those unused pubip.

Could you please guide me here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Get-AzureRMPublicIPAddress` will list out all of your public IP addresses, if they are assigned the properties don't change all that much from looking at a few of mine.

You could try using the property `DnsSettingsText`, I noticed on mine that those with `null` in this property were unassigned. You could also look at `IpConfigurationText` which contains a string similar to this one:

```
 /subscriptions/<guid>/resourceGroups/<rg>/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/<nic name>/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1
```

This tells you which network interface the public IP address is assigned to. Once you've found those unused IP addresses then just pipe out to `Remove-AzureRmPublicIpAddress`.

Something like this may work for you, but make sure you text it properly.

```
Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress | Where-Object { $_.IpConfigurationText -notlike '/subscriptions/*' } | Remove-AzureRmPublicIpAddress
```